# (partial) template specialization for bool

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggling to understand how template specialization for bool works for this slide taken from [cppcon 2017](https://youtu.be/n4ie7tPMXOQ?list=PLHTh1InhhwT6bwIpRk0ZbCA0N2p1taxd6&t=1036)

Short question: why (first) primary template handles **odd** N cases when its signature is

<..., bool = **(N % 2 == 0)**> ?

Trying to understand myself I simplified down to

```
#include<iostream>
template<unsigned N, bool =(N%2==0)> struct S { void operator()(){ std::cout << "A\n"; } };
template<unsigned N> struct S<N, true> { void operator()(){ std::cout << "B\n"; } };
int main()
{
    S<2>{}();
    S<3>{}();
}
```

which prints `B` `A`, showings same (yet mysterious to me) behavior as linked talk, but if I change  template specialization to

```
template<unsigned N> struct S<N, false> { void operator()(){ std::cout << "B\n"; } };
                                 -----
```

it prints `A` `B`: how compiler chooses between primary `S` and its specialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler always prefers the specialization over the generalization and thus will always pick it if it can.

The struct `S` has a partial template specialization that will only be picked if the second template parameter evaluates to `true`, so let's see how that works:

```
S<2>{}();
```

Here the template parameter `N` is 2 and so `2 % 2 == 0` holds true. Which means the specialization will be picked over the generalized `S` because the specialization requires the second parameter to be `true` and `B` is printed.

This isn't the case for `S<3>{}();` because `3 % 2 == 0` holds false, and thus the generalized case is used, giving you `A`.

If you swap it around and make the specialization only accept `false` for `N % 2 == 0` then the results will be the exact opposite, `2 % 2 == 0` still holds true but the specialization only accepts false so it's not picked, `3 % 2 == 0` holds false and thus it will be picked, resulting in `A B`.

Comment: so what is the `=` used for in template `bool` argument declaration?

Comment: @user1832484 it's used as a default template argument, the template argument itself is only used to help in picking the right specialization.

Comment: still not clear; given that __default__ arguments are those provided in definition and used when arguments are lacking when in invocation, both `S<2>{}();` and `S<3>{}();` lack second (`bool`) template argument so they should be seen as `S<2, true>{}();` and `S<3, false>{}();` and my first snippet should be printing `A` `B`

Comment: I got it, `S<2, true>{}();` __is__ the specialization which prints `B`, thank you @Rick Astley

Answer (score 0):

It's specialization; the compiler choose the most specialized version available.

Ignore for a moment the default value for `bool` (that transform `S<2>` in `S<2, true>` and `S<3>` in `S<3, false>`); you have

```
template <unsigned N, bool>
struct S
 { /* something */};

template <unsigned N>
struct S<N, true>
 { /* something */};
```

The first one is neutral regarding the second (the `bool` one) template parameter; so matches both `S<2, true>` and `S<3, false>`.

The second one require that the second template parameter is `true`, so matches only `S<2, true>`. And is more specialized than the first one because every match for the second template is also a match for the first one but there are matches for the first one that aren't matches for the second one (`S<3, false>`, by example).

For `S<3, false>` the compiler find only a template that matches (the first one) so choose the first one.

For `S<2, true>` the compiler find both templates that match and coose (rule of C++) the most specialized, that is the second one.

When you change the `true` in `false` you have that `S<3, false>` matches both version, so the second one is choosed, and `S<2, true>` matches only the first one.

Comment: the code you wrote is a case already clear to me, but you are neglecting the `=` (default value for `bool`): what is it for in my code?